# Android map extension library adding issue

Tags: android

In my android application i want to use Android map extension library project.
In eclipse when i am trying to add that library project in my application i follow this steps,

right click on my application -> properties -> android ->  add that library on my project

when i add that library project i can see that check mark sign which indicate android map extension is implemented and i can use it's class and all
and than simply,

apply -> ok

but problem is when i again open that properties that time that added library path is not checked.
 i want to know what is a problem exactly why can't i import it properly help me. i would like to see by screenshot but i don't have enough reputation sorry for that

Comment: I have keep my project and library in same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your library and project in same directory.

Comment: First check your library & project path by going properties-> resource. If not same Re import the library again and check the check box "COPY to work space". on importing dialog it will surely solve your problem.

Comment: i have re import so many time but it can't solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your project and the library project that import are in the same folder or the same workspace. Make sure you tick COPY TO WORKSPACE when importing the library project:

[image]